# What is no change class in NLCD 2011?

Tags: land-cover, land-classification, nlcd

I have to use the NLCD 2011 dataset and I am trying to understand the "no change" class. This class is not defined in any of the legend descriptions (Anderson classification).

What is the no change class in NLCD 2011?

Comment: Which NLCD raster are you using, exactly? Some of them track changes between previous NLCD versions and the current one.

Comment: @DanC- NLCD 2011 landcover 2011 edition. Value 0 in it is no change.
I was reading the associated paper and it seems like this product is a change detected product from NLCD 2006. So all those pixels that are "no change" did not change from 2006? But how do I know which classes do these no change pixels belong to?

Answer (score 1):

[Multi-Resolution Land Characteristics (MRLC) consortium](https://www.mrlc.gov/nlcd11_data.php) has a couple of different datasets of changes (2001-2011 & 2006-2011).  Depending on what data you are using, you are most likely looking at changes from one of those years (my assumption is 2006, but there is always some outdated stuff lurking on the internet waiting to be downloaded).